# Como corrigir o erro: Schema specified is not valid

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Modifiquei a BD do meu projeto e realizei a atualização do meu arquivo edmx, mas agora quando tento compilar está aparecendo o erro:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the 
>   ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. 
>   Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' 
>   section of the application config file. 
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information

Não sei como resolver este problema alguém tem alguma dica?

O `webconfig` do meu projecto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>-->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="bancotccEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/bancotcc.csdl|res://*/bancotcc.ssdl|res://*/bancotcc.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=tcc2012;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=bancotcc&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Por que a section sobre o Entity Framework está comentada?

Comment: me sugeriram comentar essa sessão aqui no fórum. após comentar eu conseguia conectar mas aparecia um erro de validação no método savechenges.

Comment: Bom, então, aqui não é bem um 'fórum'. Aqui é um site de perguntas e respostas, então a dinâmica é um pouco diferente. Veja este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. De qualquer forma, verifique se minha resposta te ajuda.

Comment: @user9090, lembra que eu te ajudei nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17464/como-corrigir-o-erro-atributo-name-nao-reconhecido-no-webconfig, e lembra que você deve decorar a sua classe, veja o último tópico "Outros Fatores que podem influenciar". Porque aconteceu tudo isso, você atualizou seu "Edmx" e com isso ele apagou seu Atributo decorator `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]`, então, todas as vezes que atualizar você deve configurar a sua class que herda de `DbContext` e o se web.config continua igual dessa resposta!

Comment: Sim lembrei agora, só não sabia que cada vez que eu modificasse o banco teria que recolocar o atributo.

Comment: @user9090, você alterou o Edmx vai ter que alterar e colocar o atributo novamente! pode-se criar um class partial e utilizar esse recurso que você não precisaria de ficar colocando sempre! mas, isso teria que ser outra dúvida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seção `<entityFramework>` está errada. Modifique para:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Testei mas acabou aparecendo outro erro:he Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.